# for loop not looping through my array of objects JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I am trying to loop through the array of objects below. I created a function to loop through it and return true if the username and password exist in the dataBase, else return false. However, it always returns false whether the username and password exist or not.

what could possible be wrong with it? Any hints would be super helpful!

```
const dataBase =[
        {
            username:'cristiano',
            password:'hattrick'
        },
        {
            username:'cierra',
            password:'lapuerta'
        },
        {
            username:'carlos',
            password:'elpollo'
        }
    ];

function checkDataBase(userName, passWord){
    for (let i=0; i < dataBase.length; i++){
        if (dataBase[i].username === userName && dataBase[i].passWord === passWord){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check the case of your variables. This test would work.

```
if (dataBase[i].username === userName && dataBase[i].password === passWord){
```

i would advise you to use eslint and typescript in your project or IDE. He would have pointed the error for you before execution.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it and for the advise. I am in the process of learning typescript.

Answer (score 3):

you need to write w in lower case
[image]

Comment: wow! that will do it! thanks so much I spent hours trying to figure it out. I just need it a new pair of fresh eyes!

Answer (score 1):

This check is not good because your user objects have a 'password' property and yet within the if statement you are trying to access the 'passWord' property which is non existent.

```js
if (dataBase[i].username === userName && dataBase[i].passWord === passWord)
```

Capitalization matters in javascript.

Comment: Thank you this was super helpful.